# Listing 12 prior months

Tags: java, grails, date, groovy

I have a situation that requires me to get the 12 past months in a list.

Example:

The current month is March, and the current year is 2012. So I want to get a list that looks like this:

March (2011), April (2011)...December (2011), January (2012), February (2012), and March (2012).

I've been trying to accomplish this using Date and Calendar, I didn't quite manage to get the alorithm correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a Groovy way to do it:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def today = new Date()
    println today
    12.times { i ->
        println today - (i+1).months
    }
}
```

You can read more about Groovy dates [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN0545-Dates)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete, functioning version based on doelleri's suggestion:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def today = new Date()
    13.times { i ->
        println( (today - i.months).format('MMMM (yyyy)') )
    }
}
```

The changes I made:

1. I modified the loop so that the printing could occur in the same place (instead of printing the current month in a different place).
2. I used the `format` method to render the date exactly as you requested.  If you want the output to line up nicer, try using `'MMM (yyyy)'` as the format, which uses 3-letter months.

You'll probably want to get these as a list, so you might be better off using:

```
def months
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def today = new Date()
    months = (0..13).collect { (today - it.months).format('MMMM (yyyy)') }
}
```

Which stores the month data into an array called `months`.

Comment: I like `def months = []` and then use `13.times { months << ... }`